# Batching in Custom Functions

Tags: office-js

We implemented Custom Functions with single api call and working fine. Also tried to implement as a batch in single api call to bind in selected rows. Can you please  share any working examples?

Thanks
Murugananth S

Comment: Hi, can you provide additional details? Are you trying to pass in a range of cells, or return a range of cells back?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to drag the cells by row to call api at a single request and binding the values from same. Let me  please know if anything required.

Comment: That means can we use batch calling which aggregates multiple api calls into one function api call.

Answer (score 1):

Like Keyur said, a global queue and some sort of timer to dispatch that queue would be your best bet.

For an example, see https://gist.github.com/Zlatkovsky/84c8d5749cf98009958cf6a641b22cbd

Note how the function returns a Promise as its result, as follows:

```
    function getSentimentFast(text: string): Promise<number> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            queue.add({
                text: text.substr(0, 1000),
                callback: function (sentiment) {
                    resolve(sentiment)
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

It then relies on a timer in the queue to dispatch the API calls in batches and to call the callback (which in turn will resolve the Promise).

Comment: Thanks Michael. Another thing I was stuck that getting array of excel rows (multiple selection) from excel to customfunction.js file using JSON file. I tried with dimentionality  as "matrix" instead "scalar" but still I am getting single value from excel when doing multiple selections. Please advise.

Comment: @Murugaananth, I suggest you open a new question on it, with a screenshot

Comment: I opened as new question titled "batching-in-custom-functions-using-office-js". Could you please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The recommended approach would be to queue your items/args into a global array. Each time a new request comes in, the timer is set up to continuously execute until no more items remain. You will need to declare the functions as asynchronous by setting "sync: false" in your functions.json. Checking on an example for you, and this article has an example on saving state.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview#saving-and-sharing-state

Comment: Thanks Keyur. Will try and update if anything required.

Comment: Hi Keyur, Also one more clarification that debugging of async custom functions able to do only post hosting the application but during development not able to do debug the custom functions code in .js file. For example if i select one forumulae in one cell and entered then .js file opening as dynamic (runtime) file so debugging not hitting the source code file in Visual studio. Can you please suggest on this.

Comment: We'll make a note, but for debugging, we're still working on enabling that, so the best way currently is to try it in your browser. We're going to be switching to a new JS runtime (ChakraCore on Windows) and we will share details on how to debug that, with focus starting in browser/VS code first.

Comment: You no longer need to set "sync:false" apparently